# .NET :- Finding Distinct after joining tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm assigning a task to the people based on their skills. I'm getting all the matching result in `matchings` but I need to get distinct/new task to new people.

My code allotting one task to all the people having the skill needed to complete that task.

```
var matchings = sortedSmallTask.Join(peopleSkills,
t => t.Id,
ps => ps.skill.Id,
(task, pss) => new { task , 
 _repository.People}).DistinctBy(d => d.task);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @mjwills I needed to retrive new task for new person. how to use distinct or select clause there.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Be sure to specify sample inputs in code. Be sure to be very clear what **exact** output you are aiming for.

Comment: Your code is full of issues. Why do you call `_repository.People` for each task? Why don't you do anything with `pss`? And the most important one: How for Pete's sake can you match task Ids with Skill Ids? And indeed, there's no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GroupJoin` instead of `Join`

```
var matchings = sortedSmallTask.GroupJoin(peopleSkills,
t => t.Id,
ps => ps.skill.Id,
(task, pss) => new { task , 
_repository.People}).DistinctBy(d => d.task);
```

It will act as a group by clause.